# What does UV coating do for a flash tube?

Tags: flash, studio-lighting, uv

For studio portrait lighting, is it better to have a UV coated flashtube, or a clear flashtube, and why?  Does it make a difference what ambient light there is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the UV coating can help when photographing white material, such as a wedding dress, which can flouresce when exposed to UV and give it an undesirable bluish cast.  Reference the discussion at http://photo.net/wedding-photography-forum/007pFD.

Answer (score 5):

I can't claim to be an expert on this subject, but I don't see what the advantage of a clear flashtube would be (cheaper, maybe?).  Whatever you do, make sure what you're doing is safe--being flashed with a bare quartz flash tube could result in a trip to the ER, according to [this page](http://members.misty.com/don/xesafe.html#u).